# Creation of Bullets using objects in a game

Tags: java, opengl, processing

I have some Processing code where I need to create a new rectangular box when a certain key is pressed and I need to have multiples of these on screen. I have all the code setup so that when I press a key something can happen, but I've tried to create new objects infinitely and I can't get it to work.

Code:

```
public float translateX = 0;
public float translateY = 260;
public float translateZ = 10000;

float bulletX, bulletY, bulletZ;

public int rotationBlue = 1;
public int rotationGreen = 1;
public int rotationRed = 1;

public boolean shootBool = false;
public boolean shootBoolVal = true;

void setup() {
  size(1280, 720, P3D);
  frameRate(60);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  translate(640, 360, -10000);
  fill(0);
  box(100000);
  ship();
  control();
}

void control() {
  if (keyPressed) {
    if (key == 'a' || key == 'A') {
      translateX = translateX - 5;
    }

    if (key == 'd' || key == 'D') {
      translateX = translateX + 5;
    }

    if ((key == 's' || key == 'S')) {
      translateZ = translateZ + 5;
    }

    if ((key == 'w' || key == 'W')) {
      translateZ = translateZ - 5;
    }

    if ((key == 'q' || key == 'Q')) {
      translateY = translateY - 5;
    }

    if ((key == 'e' || key == 'E')) {
      translateY = translateY + 5;
    }

    if (key == 'f' || key == 'F') {

    }
  }
}

public void ship() {
  fill(0, 0, 255);
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(3);
  translate(translateX, translateY, translateZ);
  //translate(mouseX, mouseY, 0);

  rotateX(radians(rotationBlue));
  rotateY(radians(rotationBlue));
  rotateZ(radians(rotationBlue));
  rotationBlue++;
  box(100);

  fill(0, 255, 0);
  rotateX(radians(rotationGreen));
  rotateY(radians(rotationGreen));
  rotateZ(radians(rotationGreen));
  rotationGreen--;
  box(100);

  fill(255, 0, 0);
  rotateX(radians(rotationRed));
  rotateY(radians(rotationRed));
  rotateZ(radians(rotationRed));
  rotationRed = rotationRed + 2;
  box(100);

  //translateZ = translateZ - 5;
}
```

This is all the code that I have so far. I need to be able to have it so that when I press the "F" key (which is already defined in the function control), a new box is created at the coordinates of the ship which has it's own Z direction decreasing constantly. Remember, I must be able to have more than one of these boxes at once.

I would like someone to tell me what steps I must take to do this.

Comment: What exactly are you having a problem with specifically; what's your question, please?

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps required to obtain what you need:

- define a custom `Bullet` object containing position, velocity and other required attributes, possibly also a draw function
- declare a collection of these `Bullet` objects
- when you want to shoot a bullet just add it to the collection
- to draw all the bullets iterate over the collection in the `draw()` method
- to update the attributes of all the bullets define an `update()` method which updates velocity, position etc. for every bullet, called by the `draw()` function too